# Tags redirecting to "featured" instead of "active"?

Tags: support

Whenever I click on a tag on the main site today, it displays the "featured" tab for that question, instead of the "active" tab. Is this by design? It's not happening on my other commonly visited SE sites (SO, Gaming.SE, and Workplace.SE).

I find it annoying, especially when there are no bounties for that tag, that I have to make a second click to see the entire list of questions. I also think it's possible that newer SE users might not know to click it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a "bug", but I wasn't sure what the appropriate tag would be. Please feel free to change it as necessary.

Comment: Yeah. This is not a bug. The appropriate tag is [meta-tag:support]. I don't have editing privileges so I'm commenting.

Comment: @Sinister - done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The system remembers which tab you used most recently.**

You mention that this has only been happening today, and only on SFF; this must be because you clicked on the featured tab for *some* question list and then it remembered afterwards that the featured tab is your "preferred" tab. If you order one of these lists by e.g. votes or newest instead, then the system should in turn keep *that* setting as the default.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!